# ElementClickInterceptedException error that I cannot resolve

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting the following error:

ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (288, 833)

When I manually scroll down the page to view the element, selenium finds it and clicks on it, but only if I help it by scrolling down. I have tried different methods to resolve this that I have commented out in the code, but it is still not resolved? How do I resolve this error?

```
  package mypackage;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class DynamicWebTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        
        driver.get("https://demo.opencart.com/admin/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        
        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("input-username"));
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys("demo");
        
        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("input-password"));
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys("demo");
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Login']")).click();
        
        //Close popup
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']")).isDisplayed()) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn-close']")).click();
        }
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Sales']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Orders']")).click();
        
        //get total no of pages
        String textWithTotalPages = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-sm-6 text-end']")).getText();
        int pages = getNumberOfPages(textWithTotalPages);
        System.out.println(pages);
        
        //
        for(int p = 1; p <= 2; p++) {
            WebElement active_page = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//li//span"));
            System.out.println("Active Page: "+active_page.getText());
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            //new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(active_page)).click();
            active_page.click();
            //Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            //actions.moveToElement(active_page).click().perform();
            //JavascriptExecutor e = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
            //e.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", active_page);
            
            //get number of rows
            int rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-hover']//tbody/tr")).size();
            System.out.println("No of Rows: "+rows);
            
            //read rows from each page
            for(int r=1; r<=rows; r++) {
                String orderId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-hover']//tbody//tr["+r+"]//td[2]")).getText();
                String store = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-hover']//tbody//tr["+r+"]//td[3]")).getText();
                String customer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-hover']//tbody//tr["+r+"]//td[4]")).getText();
                String status = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-bordered table-hover']//tbody//tr["+r+"]//td[5]")).getText();
                
                System.out.println(orderId+ "  "+store+"  "+customer+"  "+status);
                
            }
            
            //click next page
            String nextPage = Integer.toString(p + 1);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//li//a[text()='"+nextPage+"']")).click(); 
            
                    
            
        }
        
        
        driver.quit();
    }
        
    //extract number of pages from String 
    public static int getNumberOfPages(String text){
        
        return Integer.valueOf(text.substring(text.indexOf("(")+1, text.indexOf("Pages")-1));
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Active page never clickable. why are you trying to click on that?

Comment: You don't need this extra line of code at all `WebElement active_page = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//li//span"));
            System.out.println("Active Page: "+active_page.getText());
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            //new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(active_page)).click();
            active_page.click();`

Comment: @KunduK waiting is not solving that problem. Only way is to scroll down and click that element. It works.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, Have you read my comments properly. Those line of code is not required I said. Where said waiting required.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close this pop up`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn-close']")).click`

before you execute

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[normalize-space()='Sales']")).click();
```

This will resolve the problem for you. I have tried in WATIR, it's working for me.

Okay, So try writing this code in try catch block.

```
try{
activePage.click();
}catch(ElementClickInterceptedException e){
}
```

or scroll down the page and issue the click, it works too

```
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
Thread.sleep(2000);
activePage.click();
```

Comment: That line of code is fine. The popup is closed. The error occurs after that in  this line in the for loop: active_page.click();   Any suggestions?

Comment: I have given you the update. Can you try now? I placed that code inside try catch block, and it's working for me.

Comment: Hi, I gave you another solution as well. You have to scroll down and issue the click. I checked in ruby binding, it's working well. Check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, I made 2 changes to your code:

- Using JavascriptExecutor, scroll down to the bottom of the page and then perform `active_page.click()`
- In the second iteration since the DOM structure changes,`active_page.click()` won't work(you may get Stale element reference, Element is not attached to the page document exception), so you need to assign the web element once again

Good luck.

```
   for(int p = 1; p <= 2; p++) {
           WebElement active_page = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//li//span"));
           System.out.println("Active Page: "+active_page.getText());
           Thread.sleep(3000);
           //below 2 lines will scroll to the bottom of the page
           JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
           js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)");
           Thread.sleep(3000);
           //assigning web element to active_page once again as the DOM structure has changed
           active_page = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//li//span"));
           active_page.click();
```

Comment: Thanks. Does selenium not automatically scroll  up or down to find elements? Secondly, Why/how did the DOM structure change? I'm new to selenium.

Comment: Selenium is capable of manipulating the DOM, and hence it doesn’t require scroll to perform certain actions. However, in some cases, there are certain web elements (for ex, a submit button) that become visible only once the user has scrolled down. In such cases, automating the scroll operation becomes necessary. About second question, refer this link (https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/stale-element-reference-exception-selenium-webdriver/). If this solution has resolved the specific query you raised in this question, then accept the answer and upvote. Good luck.

Comment: I asked another question, but has been closed down as I think you marked it as a duplicate. But the issue is different and on another line. The web element is freshly assigned but getting a stale element error. Can you reopen it? DO you know what the cause of that is?

Comment: I did not mark it as duplicate nor I closed it.